# Align dropdown submenu <li> items to the right of the page, while keeping <li> items in the correct order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, css-float

In the following jsfiddle, I have demonstrated the issue I am facing. Basically I need a submenu that opens full-width and inline with the submenu list items floated to the right of the page while still keeping the list items in the correct order. I can get the menu to float right if I apply float:right to .dropdown-menu li, but then the items are in reverse order. If I apply float:right to .dropdown-menu ul and float:left to the li, the menu does not float right at all.

Is there conflicting Bootstrap code that is affecting the ul so that it doesn't float right? Is there another solution that I haven't considered?

I have considered changing the html to be in reverse order of what I need, but then it will not be in the correct order when it is viewed in mobile.

Here is an example of the issue in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kasiamcm/oqq73axb/

html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="">Something else here</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px; /*height of main menu*/
  width: 100%;
display: inline-flex;}

.dropdown-menu ul {
    float: right;}

.dropdown-menu li {
    display: inline-flex;
    float: left;}
```

Comment: So after @nathanielw answered the original question correctly, I realized that my original jsfiddle did not precisely illustrate my question. Here is a better example of my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/kasiamcm/7eswyw8s/1/

Comment: Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/uoowh25c/1/

Answer (score 0):

In this case setting `text-align: right` on the `ul` containing the dropdown items (and not floating the items at all) will put the items on the right.

So your CSS becomes:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px; /*height of main menu*/
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oqq73axb/2/

Comment: I have revised my original jsfiddle example to be more specific about the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/kasiamcm/o2cd50yn/. As you can see, only the last menu is displayed in this case, and only the last menu is aligned to the right side of the page. I can make the dropdown menus display the correct menu, but then the submenu is still not aligned to the right side of the page. https://jsfiddle.net/kasiamcm/7eswyw8s/

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle with code that most closely matches my question: https://jsfiddle.net/kasiamcm/7eswyw8s/1/